# How to write a function to generate a sequence of points in R?

Tags: r, density-function, uniform-distribution

This is the PDF that I am dealing with:

```
fx = 0.3 if (0<=x<1) 
0.1 if (1<=x<2) 
0.25 if (2<=x<3)
0.15 if (3<=x<4)
0.2 if (4<=x<5) 
0 otherwise
```

I have to write a function `gen_xy` that will generate a sequence of points `(X,Y)` uniformly distributed in `(0,5)x(0,0.5)` until one lies in the region under the curve of `y=fx(x)`

This is my code so far:

```
    fx <- function(x) c(0, 0.3,0.1,0.25,0.15,0.20, 0)
    [findInterval(x, c(-Inf, 0:5,  Inf))]

    x <- runif(n,0,5)
    fx <- stepfun(x = 0:5, y = c(0,0.3,0.1,0.25,0.15,0.20,0))
    plot(fx, ylim = c(0,0.5),xlim = c(0,5), main = 'f(x)')
```

Now this is my attempt at writing the code for my function:

```
    gen_xy <- function()
    {
     done=0
     while(done==0)
     {
      x=runif(1,0,5)
      y=runif(1,0,0.5)
      print(c("x,y",c(x,y)))
      if(y < fx(x))
      {
       done=1
      }
     }
     xy=c(x,y)
     xy
    }
```

But I think the part `if(y < fx)` is wrong?

I then need to generate a sample of 1000 points and plot them to check if they are an appropriate sample from under the curve of `y=fx`.

How would I go about writing such a code?

Comment: Given your explanation, I don't think the part $if(y<fx)$ is wrong. But if your intention is to implement rejection sampling (which appears to be the case), then you need some more work. Can you clarify why you think that part is wrong?

Comment: I suppose I don't think it's wrong per se but as you said, I think I need to add a bit more in - I'm just not sure exactly what or how.

Comment: Is this something along the lines of what I need to do:

       nreps=1000
       randomxy=array(0,c(2,nreps))
       for(i in 1:nreps)
      {
       randomxy[,i]=pr2_gen_xy()
       }
 
       points(randomxy[1,],randomxy[2,], col="blue")
 
      hist(randomxy[1,],prob=TRUE,xlab="X     values",ylab="Probability density",
 main="Histogram for Exercise 2")
 curve(fx,add=TRUE,col="red")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's begin with generalities that would apply in any statistical computing environment.

**It is important to be efficient**, because random variates are usually generated in great big batches for simulations and other calculations.

To achieve efficiency, **generate lots of random variates at once**, store them in a buffer, and fetch the values from the buffer as needed.

One way to implement this in most languages is to **pass the buffer as an argument** to the random number generation function: this makes its role explicit and provides for maintaining separate streams of random variates.

Another important engineering strategy is to **avoid overwork**.  Thus, it is wise to estimate how many "probe" points will be needed in order to be reasonably sure of obtaining the desired number of values, without generating too many such probes.  This can be done by multiplying the desired number of points by the reciprocal of the fraction of the rejection region they will occupy and then adding a small multiple of the sampling standard deviation of that count: see the use of `factor` and `n0` in the following example.

---

Here is a quick implementation of a function `rcustom` in `R` to illustrate these strategies.  Its arguments are

- `n` is the number of random variates requested.
- `pdf` is the list of PDF heights corresponding to the intervals $[0,1)$, $[1,2)$, etc.
- `upper` is an upper bound for the y-coordinates of the probes.
- `buffer` is the buffer returned by any previous call; its values will be used first before any new values are generated.

The code:

```
rcustom <- function(n=1, pdf=c(0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.15, 0.2), upper=max(pdf), buffer) {
  # Assert min(pdf) >= 0 && max(pdf) <= upper
  if (missing(buffer)) buffer <- matrix(numeric(0), 2) # Initialize a buffer
  factor <- upper / mean(pdf)                          # Total area / sampled area
  n.needed <- n
  while(n.needed > 0) {
    n.inBuffer <- dim(buffer)[2]
    n.toMake <- n.needed - n.inBuffer
    if (n.toMake > 0) {
      n0 <- ceiling(n.toMake * factor + 
                      5 * sqrt(n.toMake * factor))     # Overestimate how many needed
      x <- runif(n0, 0, length(pdf))                   # Generate x-coordinates
      y <- runif(n0, 0, upper)                         # Generate y-coordinates
      i <- y <= pdf[ceiling(x)]                        # Select those less than the PDF
      buffer <- cbind(buffer, rbind(x[i], y[i]))       # Augment the buffer at the end
    }
    n.needed <- n - dim(buffer)[2]
  }
  # Return the points as a 2 by n array, along with anything left in the buffer.
  return(list(xy=matrix(buffer[, 1:n], 2), buffer=matrix(buffer[, -(1:n)], 2)))
}
```

As an example of its application, look at its simplest form of invocation:

```
> set.seed(17)
> (vars <- rcustom())
$xy
          [,1]
[1,] 0.7752542
[2,] 0.2339909

$buffer
           [,1]      [,2]         [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 4.84189404 2.3413154 3.8840982586 2.6939857 0.9355178
[2,] 0.05818318 0.1302694 0.0006823554 0.2490249 0.2845491
```

The point `(0.7752542, 0.2339909)` is returned along with a new buffer filled with the next five points.

To continue using the buffer, pass it to the next call to `rcustom`:

```
> rcustom(buffer=vars$buffer)
$xy
           [,1]
[1,] 4.84189404
[2,] 0.05818318

$buffer
          [,1]         [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 2.3413154 3.8840982586 2.6939857 0.9355178
[2,] 0.1302694 0.0006823554 0.2490249 0.2845491
```

Notice how `$xy` was the first column of the old buffer and the new buffer is now one column shorter.

Let's see an industrial-strength use:

```
> # Time the generation of a lot of variates
> system.time({vars <- rcustom(10^6); u <- t(vars$xy)})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.36    0.05    0.40 

> dim(vars$buffer) # How many values are wasted ?
[1]    2 3937
```

It is indeed efficient: a million pairs were generated in 0.4 seconds and only 3937 extra pairs were produced to do so: less than 0.4% of the total.  (It is less efficient when you generate y-values up to $0.5$, because more are rejected.  Use the option `upper=0.5` in the preceding timing code to assess the difference: I find the execution time increases by 40%.)

As a check, let's plot some of these pairs in a scatterplot, using the intended PDF as a reference:

```
# Plot the first 1000 values.
colors <- palette(terrain.colors(5, alpha=0.5))
plot(c(0,5), c(0,.5), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y")
rect(0:4, 0, 1:5, c(0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.15, 0.2), col=colors, border=NA)
points(u[1:1000, ])
```

[image: Histogram and scatterplot]

Comment: This is really useful stuff but I think I'll need to bit of time to get my head around it and actually use it. Could you have a look at my other question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56501/histograms-and-cdfs